# find the array index which its element is most near greater than a value

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a sorted array.

```
x = [1, 10, 12, 16, 19, 20, 21, ....]
```

for any given number `y` which is between `[x[0], x[-1]]`, I want to find the index of the element which is the most near greater than `y`, for example, if `y = 0`, it returns `0`, if `y = 18`, it returns `4`

Is there a function available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any external library, you can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/bisect.html)

```
i = bisect.bisect_right(x, y)
```

*i* will be the index of the element you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Given the sorted nature, we can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(x,y,'right')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.argmin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html?highlight=argmin#numpy.argmin) on the absolute value of the difference:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 10, 12, 16, 19, 20, 21])

def find_closest(x,y):
    return (np.abs(x-y)).argmin()

for y in [0,18]:
    print(find_closest(x,y))

0
4
```

Comment: It's not efficient enough as we are handing a sorted array